# How to write a python script for downloading?

Tags: python, download, python-2.7

I want to download some files from this site: http://www.emuparadise.me/soundtracks/highquality/index.php

But I only want to get certain ones.

Is there a way to write a python script to do this? I have intermediate knowledge of python

I'm just looking for a bit of guidance, please point me towards a wiki or library to accomplish this

thanks,
Shrub

[Here's a link to my code](http://pastebin.com/3ihc6A1d)

Comment: I would recommend using BeautifulSoup to parse the page and extract the links that you want. From there, just make a few methods that break down your problem into simple steps.

Comment: For the downloading part, the built-in `urllib2` (http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2) is the easiest way; the sample code in the documentation is easy enough to follow. For the parsing, BeautifulSoup is the best way to scrape arbitrary HTML; if you know you've got valid XHTML or HTML 5 there are other options; if you can get the information in machine-readable XML or JSON instead of human-readable HTML in the first place, I'd do that.

Comment: @abarnert how about using `wget` with `subprocess` module for downloading files?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Sure, you could do that, but why? It's not any easier than `urllib2`, it'll be harder to debug, and it introduces a dependency on a tool that isn't installed by default on Mac, Windows, FreeBSD, some linux distros, etc. Using `wget` as a replacement for both the downloading _and_ the parsing might be a reasonable solution, but in that case there's no need for any Python at all.

Comment: @abarnert thanks, It makes more sense now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at the page. The links seem to redirect to another page, where the file is hosted, clicking which downloads the file.

I would use [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to follow the required links to the right page, and then use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [lxml](http://lxml.de/) to parse the resultant page to get the filename.

Then it's a simple matter of opening the file using [urlopen](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) and writing its contents out into a local file like so:

```
f = open(localFilePath, 'w')
f.write(urlopen(remoteFilePath).read())
f.close()
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much! Do I replace localFilePath and remoteFilePath with my desired directory?

Comment: `localFilePath` is your desired complete pathname—directory plus filename. `remoteFilePath` is the URL.

Comment: `localFilePath` will contain the directory where you want to save the music. For example, `localFilePath` could be `/home/username/Downloads/OnlineMusic/file1.flac`

Comment: Thanks. With mechanize and BS, will I have to specify each URL?

Comment: You will have to somehow identify the links that matter to you. This can be done by checking the URL itself or by the anchor text associated with it

Comment: @inspectorG4dget have made good progress with your help, however I am having trouble writing the file i do ' f = open(/home/usr/Desktop, 'w') ` i get an error on the file path. ' IOERROR: {ERRNO21 } (the path) is a directory `

Comment: @user67784: suppose you are trying to download `file1.flac`. Then, do `f=open('/home/usr/Desktop/file1.flac', 'w')`. It doesn't matter if this file doesn't actually exist on your desktop - it will be created

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I just realized this right before you posted. When I supply a url and run the script, my desired file gets created however it is a 0byte file. How can I fix this?

Comment: I can't do much without looking at your code. Try: (1) close file after writing to it. (2) check to make sure that you've read the remote contents properly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17208/discussion-between-inspectorg4dget-and-user67784)

Answer (score 1):

Make a url request for the page. Once you have the source, filter out and get urls.

The files you want to download are urls that contain a specific extension. It is with this that you can do a regular expression search for all urls that match your criteria. 
After filtration, then do a url request for each matched url's data and write it to memory.

Sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
import sys
import urllib

#Your sample url
sampleUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com"
urlAddInfo = urllib.urlopen(sampleUrl)
data = urlAddInfo.read()

#Sample extensions we'll be looking for: pngs and pdfs
TARGET_EXTENSIONS = "(png|pdf)"
targetCompile = re.compile(TARGET_EXTENSIONS, re.UNICODE|re.MULTILINE)

#Let's get all the urls: match criteria{no spaces or " in a url}
urls = re.findall('(https?://[^\s"]+)', data, re.UNICODE|re.MULTILINE)

#We want these folks
extensionMatches = filter(lambda url: url and targetCompile.search(url), urls)

#The rest of the unmatched urls for which the scrapping can also be repeated.
nonExtMatches = filter(lambda url: url and not targetCompile.search(url), urls)


def fileDl(targetUrl):
  #Function to handle downloading of files.
  #Arg: url => a String
  #Output: Boolean to signify if file has been written to memory

  #Validation of the url assumed, for the sake of keeping the illustration short
  urlAddInfo = urllib.urlopen(targetUrl)
  data = urlAddInfo.read()
  fileNameSearch = re.search("([^\/\s]+)$", targetUrl) #Text right before the last slash '/'
  if not fileNameSearch:
     sys.stderr.write("Could not extract a filename from url '%s'\n"%(targetUrl))
     return False
  fileName = fileNameSearch.groups(1)[0]
  with open(fileName, "wb") as f:
    f.write(data)
    sys.stderr.write("Wrote %s to memory\n"%(fileName))
  return True

#Let's now download the matched files
dlResults = map(lambda fUrl: fileDl(fUrl), extensionMatches)
successfulDls = filter(lambda s: s, dlResults)
sys.stderr.write("Downloaded %d files from %s\n"%(len(successfulDls), sampleUrl))

#You can organize the above code into a function to repeat the process for each of the
#other urls and in that way you can make a crawler.
```

The above code is written mainly for Python2.X. However, [I wrote a crawler that works on any version starting from 2.X](https://github.com/odeke-em/crawlers/blob/master/fileDownloader.py)

Answer (score 0):

Why yes! 5 years later and, not only is this possible, but you've now got a *lot* of ways to do it.
I'm going to avoid code-examples here, because mainly want to help break your problem into segments and give you some options for exploration:

### Segment 1: GET!

If you **must** stick to the `stdlib`, for either python2 or python3, `urllib[n]`***** is what you're going to want to use to pull-down something from the internet.
So again, if you don't want dependencies on other packages:

- `urllib` or `urllib2` or maybe another `urllib[n]` I'm forgetting about.

#### If you don't have to restrict your imports to the Standard Library:

you're in luck!!!!! You've got:

- `requests` with docs [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/). ***`requests` is the golden standard for gettin' stuff off the web with python. I suggest you use it.***

- `uplink` with docs [here](https://uplink.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html). It's relatively new & for more programmatic client interfaces.
- `aiohttp` via `asyncio` with docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html). `asyncio` got included in python >= 3.5 only, and it's also extra confusing. That said, it if you're willing to put in the time it can be ridiculously efficient for exactly this use-case.

...I'd also be remiss not to mention one of my favorite tools for crawling:

- `fake_useragent` repo [here](https://github.com/hellysmile/fake-useragent). Docs like seriously not necessary.

### Segment 2: Parse!

So again, if you *must* stick to the stdlib and not install anything with `pip`, you get to use the extra-extra fun and secure (<==extreme-sarcasm) `xml` builtin module. Specifically, you get to use the:

- `xml.etree.ElementTree()` with docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree).

It's worth noting that the `ElementTree` object is what the pip-downloadable `lxml` package is based on, and made make easier to use. If you want to recreate the wheel and write a bunch of your own complicated logic, using the default `xml` module is your option.

#### If you don't have to restrict your imports to the Standard Library:

- `lxml` with docs [here](https://lxml.de/index.html#documentation). As i said before, `lxml` is a wrapper around `xml.etree` that makes it human-usable & implements all those parsing tools you'd need to make yourself. However, as you can see by visiting the docs, it's not easy to use by itself. This brings us to...
- `BeautifulSoup` aka `bs4` with docs [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-using-tag-names). ***BeautifulSoup makes everything easier. It's my recommendation for this.***

### Segment 3: GET GET GET!

This section is nearly exactly the same as "Segment 1," except you have a bunch of links not one.
The only thing that changes between this section and "Segment 1" is my recommendation for what to use: `aiohttp` here will download **way** faster when dealing with several URLs because it's allows you to download them in parallel.******

---

* - (where `n` was decided-on from python-version to ptyhon-version in a somewhat frustratingly arbitrary manner. Look up which `urllib[n]` has `.urlopen()` as a top-level function. You can read more about this naming-convention clusterf**k [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html), [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen), and [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.html).)

****** - (This isn't totally true. It's more sort-of functionally-true at human timescales.)

Answer (score -1):

I would use a combination of wget for downloading - http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/the-ultimate-wget-download-guide-with-15-awesome-examples/#more-1885  and BeautifulSoup http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ for parsing the downloaded file

Comment: Why use wget? If you just want to download the entire contents of a URL, that's one line with `urllib2.urlopen`, while with `wget` you need at least one line of `subprocess` and another line to read the file, plus you've got a temporary file sitting around that you didn't need and have to manage, etc. Also, that means you need to install wget if you're on Mac, Win, FreeBSD, any of the linux distros that doesn't install it by default, etc.